Why did the drywall tape fail in my garage? How can I fix it?
House forty years old, been here five years.  Bits of drywall tape regularly dislodge and fall on the floor or car and I'm getting sick of it.  I have begun scraping off the loose bits, but the middle parts of the drywall have very well adhered texture -- starting say six inches away from the joint.
Any guesses as to why this happened?  And how can I tape if I can't really feather my edges due to existing texture near the joints?

Do you know how the tape was applied?  It should be mud, then tape placed on/in the wet mud, and more mud over it.  It looks like not enough or no mud placed first.

Crip,  I don't know how it was applied; it was before my time.  Thanks

That was a bad tape job and if you are in a high humidity area it was doomed to fail.
Get rid of all the paper tape. Use mesh tape. It does not require hotmud.
Apply the mesh tape and mud over it. It is sticky, but it will only stick for a few minutes when overhead, so apply maybe 10 feet of tape and mud over it and move on.

Why mesh instead of paper?  Ease of application/learning curve, or do you think it will hold more poorly even if applied correctly?

I think it's more of a preference. Paper tape may require a bit more care on install to make sure mud is underneath. Mesh tape the mud just pushes through, so you can just stick it to the surface. However, finishing work is more with mesh tape, since it is textured and thicker it requires more feathering and cate to not expose the mesh texture. Given this is a garage ceiling, many of those details may not matter to you, making mesh tape easier overall.

@Adam, all of your concerns are correct.  I'm not a fan of paper tape, but that is me.

I used to have so much trouble with paper tape that I'd dip it in water before applying it to get a better bond. Now that I'm more skilled with a knife I rarely have bubbles. It's a matter of practice, and paper tape is easier to finish, as blarg says. Mesh often left me with protruding fiber, which is a pain.

Some of the other answers have hinted at this, but let me be explicit: There's no mud behind the tape.
Paper drywall tape uses drywall mud (not to be confused with spackle) as the "glue" to hold it on. You typically skim coat the joints, then press the tape into the mud. Once it's firmed up some, you start coating over the tape. Once coated, the tape is invisible (modern drywall even tapers some into the edges for that reason).
Where your tape has come off, there's mostly nothing but clean drywall. It's impressive it stayed up there as long as it did.

And how can I tape if I can't really feather my edges due to existing texture near the joints?

Let me go in a different direction here: scrape your ceiling texture off. You can mud the taped areas with fiberglass mesh tape but the newly mudded areas will stick out like sore thumbs (the new mud/spackle will be whiter than the old textured mud). Instead, take a spray bottle with water and scrape it with a metal putty knife (which you will need to re-tape the ceiling).
Once you've removed all the texture, let it dry, sand it flat, then take your putty knife and some mud and properly tape the joints. Once dry, sand it flat and then paint it. Makes for a far easier maintenance if you every need to fix or change something.

I would agree except that the bare areas where the mud has let go is wider than the tape. If it was just tape applied dry I would expect that 1) the bare channel would be exactly that width, and 2) all the tape in the garage would be badly blistered.

Take a look at the joint running crosswise in the center of the photo. A lot more is coming loose than just the tape.

Either no 'mud'/plaster  behind the tape, or else it has not adhered at all to the plasterboard above. There are some indications of the latter, as @isherwood notes.

I don't see stains, but this usually indicates a moisture issue.
Could be excessive humidity if there isn't a leak, given lack of stains. You may need more ventilation to resolve that.
Perhaps just a crappy taping job in this case, though? Looks like there was no mud under the tape in many places from the pictures. That's not how drywall tape is supposed to be done.
You'll need to scrape or sand off the texture near the joints if you want it to look nice. Then again, it's a garage, not a living room, so visible joints might not be the end of the world - your call.

I can't understand how they got the tape to stay on the ceiling without mud behind it.  Maybe it was masking tape?

If this is an external garage (especially with a flat asphalted roof), the excessive humidity may be the first sign that the external roof coating is failing. Mould will be the second. Only then actual rainwater coming through. If internal, check the ventilation.

It looks like only the joint tape is coming off.
It could be due to improperly mounting, or other reasons.
Anyway, replace the tape with perforated tape that will hold better.
the perforated tape is made from fiber not paper  (it is stronger). The mud penetrates the holes and provides adhesion to the drywall. The paper tape needs two steps. First a mud layer then the tape then another mud layer. In you case the first layer is missing.

I believe mesh requires hot mud, though, so just be prepared.

I did not know mesh holds better than paper.  Is that only in high humidity areas like garages, or everywhere?  I'm new.

"Masking tape"?

Mesh doesn't hold better unless the joint wasn't done well. Paper tape, properly applied, holds exactly as well as the mud behind it, just as mesh does.

@Adam it holds better than paper because the mud penetrates the mesh and provides better bond. It is made out of fiber which is stronger than paper. It does not requires special mud.

@Traveler I thought mesh was for fixing larger holes and tape was for seams. After checking a few sites, it seems the consensus is that paper tape is stronger once embedded in mud and dry.

You need to provide a link to show where the image came from. Just saying or showing it was found on the web does not meet the Stack Exchange policy.

I'll chime in. There's a lot of wisdom and experience on display here, but I have my own theory. Some observations, to start:

The tape job may have been done properly. I see more than just the tape letting go, which counters the argument that the tape was (somehow) put up without mud behind it.

I don't see evidence of paint or anything on the drywall that would've prevented a good bond by the joint compound.

I don't see evidence of moisture, nor does this look like what I'd expect to see if moisture was the cause.


Therefore, I think the wrong product was used in the original finish job. I have no idea what that might have been, but spackle is a good suspect. Could also have been plaster, though that probably would've worked fine. The long and short of it is that whatever it is did not bond to the drywall wrapper properly.
Pull it all down. Scrape away anything that's loose or soft. Re-tape with quality joint compound and your choice of tape. I don't think it matters whether you use paper or mesh here. Scrape away some of the texture and just feather it out over 12-16" on each side of the joint. That's what a pro would do.

There are multiple reasons this happens, in order of cause.
#1. No insulation above the drywall (If applicable)
#2. Garage is not heated, if not kept 50F or above this will happen.
This happens due to movement and temperature differentials.  If this was caused by poor tape application, the interior of the house would be failing in the same manner.  Perhaps a high glue joint compound like taping compound instead of all purpose may have made a difference, but it likely will have failed in a similar manner.
I really don't recommend mesh tape, it will fail unless installed with setting type compound.  Properly installed Drywall tape has a slight tension after it dries and it is not as weak as on would think.
Sources:
In installing drywall as a pro, I had numerous situations where the garage wasn't insulated, and in the winter it would crack before I'd left the job.  Other situations where the garage wasn't heated would always crack out in a few years, so I started telling customers that if it was important they needed to keep the garage a minimum temperature.
About mesh tape, I was called to fixed enough mesh tape + joint compound jobs to realize it wasn't a good way to tape.  A drywall acquaintance of mine told me of a pro that finished a house (under pressure) without any tape, only hot mud.  As of some years later, the house was reasonably crack free.

USG used to have a page comparing paper tape and mesh tape, and they specifically stated that mesh tape was a weaker joint unless hot mud (setting compound) was used - unfortunately that page has gone to the great 404 in the sky, or been relocated somewhere I can't find it. They had test results showing that with drying type compound, paper tape was a stronger joint.

@Ecnerwal. Is this the info you referenced?  https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/matching-joint-compound-with-proper-joint-tape-white-paper-en-usa-J2140.pdf

A couple of comments on the comments and the answers.  I will give you the full scoop.

Most guys who do garages use an adhesive when taping which I am guessing they did here - they will literally spray it on.   There will not be mud at all.  All of this type of tape will fail unless you live in a very tempered climate.   It is a terrible practice and I would never allow it.   For literally $100 (materials and time) in today's money - that is just mudding it right not full finished job.    Even a tiny tiny bit of mud behind the tape would have probably kept it up just fine.

To add on to this...  This has nothing to do with insulation above the garage.   So please add insulation but that's not helping your issue.  Also I have finished many many a garage in the midwest where it is high humidity and freezing winters.   Again the temp factors just making it happen faster.
To add more... It is very weird/uncommon that they would go to the trouble of texturing without adding a little bit of mud for the tape to stick.   The idea of texturing is that you have to do little to know mudding AFTER the tape is installed - CORRECTLY.     They have taken the normal half-ass garage drywall install and degraded it.  It would be better with no texture - tell you later.
Further on the texture... normally this is done if the space above is finished.   Since I see an attic entrance I am assuming all or most of the space above the garage is not part of the house.   If there are finished areas above the garage this would not meet code in my area.

What do people with failing tape do?    Add a little mud and retape.   That is why I mentioned before that the texture makes it much harder on you.

What should you do?   If you could care less about how this looks then just mud and tape it.    If you want it to look good you probably need to get a sander and a really good mask and sand the texture off.

What would I do?   I would sand off texture, mud/tape, and hit it with 2 coats of an oil based primer.   The oil based paint will protect from things like this happening (yes it will stink for a month).

Use mesh tape? Mesh tape comes in a variety of thickness, get the thinnest if using it.   I have two rolls in my basement and one is almost 3x as thick as the other.   That being said you can use mesh tape but it inherently has issues.   The first is even with the thinnest tape it will require way more mud and coats to cover.    Second mesh has a propensity to "pop".  In a hot garage it's not the choice.   Yea if you put three layers of mud prime and oil based paint you are probably OK but nobody that does drywall and knows their job uses mesh on sheetrock on garage ceiling.



A pro would never use mesh period. If they do, I would not hire them.  Remember high ceilings are done with a bazooka. Never enough mud. Besides the lack of heat amd temp difference are the leading factors for cracks and paper falling.

This doesn't answer the question. Please take the [tour] and see [answer].
